# Allays return value from left table in join

Tags: sql, left-join, where-clause, sql-null

I have 2 tables
A and B

A has cols(AKey, val1, val2)
B has Cols(BKey,Akey, ValX, valY)

i have the following query

```
    select a.Val1,a.Val2,b.ValX
    from A
    Left Join B on a.AKey = b.Akey
    where a.Akey ={someValue}
    and ((b.valY ={aDifferentVal}) or (b.valY is NULL))
```

The situation is that i always want to return the values from table A.
and this works when {aDifferentVal} exists in the the join, it also works when there are no values in table B for the Join, However when there are values in table be for the Join but none of these are {aDifferentVal} then the query return nothing, and i still want the values from table A.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the condition on the `left join`ed table from the `where` clause to the `on` clause of the join - otherwise they become mandatory, and rows where they are not fullfilled are filered out (here this removes rows that match but whose `valy` does not match `{adifferentval}`):

```
select a.val1,a.val2,b.valx
from a
left join b 
    on  b.akey = a.akey
    and b.valy = {adifferentval}
where a.akey = {somevalue}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the conditions on the *second* table to the `on` clause:

```
select a.Val1,a.Val2,b.ValX
from A Left Join
     B
     on a.AKey = b.Akey and (b.valY ={aDifferentVal})
where a.Akey = {someValue}
```

Filtering in the `where` clause (sort of) turns the outer join into an inner join.  Your version is slightly better, because it is checking for `NULL`.  However, the rows that match are:

- The A values that have no match in B at all.
- The A values that match the condition you specify.

What gets filtered out are A values that match a row in B but none of the matches have the condition you specify.